# ¿Puede una tabla tener varias relaciones con otra tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda estoy creando la siguiente tabla:

```
 ---------------------------
|         Master           |
 ---------------------------
| COD_MAS        | int     |
| COD_USU1       | int     |
| FECHA          | date    |
| COD_USU2       | int     |
| FECHA          | date    |
| COD_USU3       | int     |
----------------------------
```

Como pueden observar tengo `la relación` con la `tabla usuarios` repetida 3 veces `(COD_USU)`, ya que tengo que capturar en varias ocaciones los diferentes usuarios que insertan en la `tabla Master` y capturar la fecha, mi duda es `¿esta relación esta bien?` `¿o una tabla solo puede tener una relación con la misma?`

Muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: ¿Es posible registrar mas de tres usuarios? ¿Por qué los tres usuarios están asociados al campo COD_MAS?

Answer (score 3):

Sí se pueden tener múltiples llaves foránea que apunten a una misma llave primaria. Como has visto, es común con tablas de usuarios cuando uno crea un registro, otro lo autoriza, otro lo revisa, etc. O también en alguna tabla de transferencias bancarias en las que hay una columna de cuenta que envía y otra de cuenta que recibe y ambas columnas apuntan a una tabla de cuentas bancarias.

Por otro lado, debes considerar que las columnas sean atributos distintos y no sólo sean multiples instancias del mismo atributo que requerirían una tabla aparte para tener las tablas normalizadas.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede. La cardinalidad de la relación se llama Uno a Muchos (1:N). En una relación de uno a muchos, un registro de una tabla se puede asociar a uno o varios registros de otra tabla. Por ejemplo, cada cliente puede tener varios pedidos de ventas o Un padre puede tener muchos hijos pero un hijo solo puede tener un padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo necesitas crear un código de usuario 'COD_USU' y en cada tabla de consulta lo haces por el código de usuario.

Cuando desees insertar en la tabla Master puedes hacerlo así:

```
INSERT INTO t_master (COD_MAS, COD_USU, FECHA)VALUES (1,1,'2019-04-25');
INSERT INTO t_master (COD_MAS, COD_USU, FECHA)VALUES (1,2,'2019-04-25');
```

Y cuando desees consultar puedes hacerlo asi:

```
SELECT 
tm.*,
usr.nombre
FROM t_master AS tm
JOIN t_usuarios AS usr ON usr.COD= tm.COD_USU
```

Lo que te traerá todos los datos de t_master y el nombre del usuario que le corresponda a su código en la t_usuarios.